# strrep MAtlab function

Tags: matlab

I would like to remove the first letter and replace the second one by its lowercase

Example :
`a = 'iSvalid'` to `a = 'svalid'`

I've tried `strrep( a,'i','')` which gives `'Svalid'` but I would like also to convert the first capital letter to lower case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>> a = 'iSvalid';
>> b = strcat(lower(a(2)), a(3:end))

b =

svalid
```

You can also use brackets:

```
>> b = [lower(a(2)) a(3:end)]

b =

svalid
```

Answer (score 0):

For a general solution, which will e.g. work on cell arrays of strings, or on multiple words in the same string, there is `regexprep`:

```
a = 'iSvalid';
%# discard first letter of word, replace second by lower-case version
b = regexprep(a,'\<\w(\w)','${lower($1)}')

b =
svalid
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version os @petrichor's answer. I've separated each function to make the code more readable.

```
a = 'isValid';

b = a(2:end);
b(1) = lower(b(1));
```